# Promote a clerk if his salary is greater than 1000 and update his salary by 10%

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Write a Parameter Cursor program that promotes CLERK who earn more than 1000 to SR CLERK and increase the salary by 10%. Pass CLERK as a parameter to the Cursor.  Use cursor with Update Clause.

My code:

```
declare
  cursor c_promote(v_job varchar2) is 
  select empno from emp 
  where job=v_job and sal>1000 
  for update of job,sal nowait;
begin
  for emp_record in c_promote('CLERK') loop
    update emp set job='SR CLERK' 
    where empno=emp_record.empno;
    update emp set sal=sal+sal*0.1 
    where empno=emp_record.empno;
  end loop;
end;
```

My code does the work but I don't find it correct so can someone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Can you share the table and the data? And the result of your procedure call? And what you expected? For tables, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) for a tool to make ascii tables.

Comment: A cursor is totally unnecessary for this and highly not recommended.

Comment: *"My code does the work but  i dont find it correct"* What do you mean by this? What is wrong? We can't suggest anything until we know what you're expecting us to fix.

Comment: Clearly this is a homework or tutorial assignment (no one experienced with SQL would ever use a cursor for this). But as you indicated it works but just doesn't "feel" good - and that is a correct assessment. The problem is the use of 2 update statements to update the same row - not good. I suggest you look into the basic [Update syntax](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php) and then [Where Current Of](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php) clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a small procedure and pass v_job and update it in a single update statement rather than using cursor

```
 Update emp set job='SR CLERK' , sal=sal+sal*0.1
    where sal>1000 and job = v_job;
```